# How to replace compounds with special characters (e.g. +⃗)

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I have a string with compound characters assembled of RegEx special characters. (e.g. (⃗ and +⃗ ). Now I want to replace them with something else using javascript on nodejs.

The problem is, that the interpreter thinks the + in the compound is a special character and throws this exception: `SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /+⃗/: Nothing to repeat`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your regex as

```
var regex = /\+\u20d7/; // for +⃗
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! But why does replacing `/\u20d7/` also work in other compounds, but `/ ⃗/` not?

Comment: I think it's just that JavaScript regular expressions are kind-of messed up with characters outside the basic 7-bit ASCII range.

Comment: ⃗ is already a compound from `\u20d7` and a space character. That's why it's not working in other compounds.